# Is it possible to add a crystal report to a tabcontrol in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, crystal-reports

I have to add a crystal report to a tab item from a tabcontrol in Silverlight.

Is it possible to do this without using 3rd party controls, just with usual controls on Visual Studio ? And if it is possible, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can certainly export the report to HTML format with code and display *that* in the silverlight control.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.
Plus there's no way of displaying an HTML content inside a Silverlight application; so you cannot export the report in HTML format in order to display it either.
A Silverlight application runs within a sandbox provided by the Silverlight plugin, and you cannot have an HTML document or element rendered in it.

So your best shot would be to either code a custom reporting service inside your application, or fire up the Crystal Reports on a new window or a separate HTML layer.